# An issue with default fonts

Tags: fonts

I think that I am using the default fonts. When in bold I for example have
[image]

however, the default bold should look like

[image]

I have tried

```
 \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Could anybody help?

Here is the list of my packages:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}
\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0in,%
        left=0.5in,right=0.5in,top=0.8in,bottom=1in,%
        footskip=.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{seqsplit}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{amsmath} % Imports amsmath
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{physics} %Allows for differentials
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig,lipsum}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor,soul}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{slashed}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Comment: You haven't furnished nearly enough information for anyone to be able to venture a meaningful diagnosis of, let alone devise a decent cure for, the situation at hand. Please provide a minimally compilable example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end[document}`, that generates the problem behavior you wish to fix.

Comment: Mico, apologies.  I have a lot of code in my document. I will shortly upload a list of the packages.

Comment: @Mico I have now done so.

Comment: No you have still not provided any usable test file, however you are not using the deafult fonts you are using the `libertine` package to use the linux libertine fonts/

Comment: why specify `graphicx` 5 times? or `eso-pic` twice?

Comment: In addition to loading `graphicx` 5 [!] times and `eso-pic` twice, why load `enumitem` 3 times, and `amsmath`, `amsfonts`, `amssymb`, `amsthm`, `fancyhdr`, `lipsum`, `mathtools`, and `tikz` twice? Nothing good will ever come from such redundancy.

Answer (score 2):

Your code snippets may be boiled down to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine} % load "Linux Libertine" text font

\begin{document}
\textbf{Theorem}
\end{document}
```

This test document produces

[image]

because the instruction `\usepackage{libertine}` informs LaTeX that the "Linux Libertine" text font should be used.

If you didn't intend to use the Libertine text fonts, and if you prefer to use the Latin Modern text (and math) fonts instead, you should replace `\usepackage{libertine}` with `\usepackage{lmodern}`. That'll produce

[image]